# Change close button tooltip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i have to change my **form close button** tooltip from "Close" to "Other text", does anyone know how can i access that button, so i can perform the switch?

Comment: Do you mean the "X" on the top right hand of the window, or a button you have added to the form with the texted "Close"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly impossible.

You could hide the form's title bar and re-create it from scratch, but this is going to take a lot of effort.

Alternatively, you could use a third-party library to give your app an Office-style ribbon UI, making sure that library gives you the ability to change title bar button tooltips.

**Edit:** You could hide the form's title bar close button, put an ordinary button on the form, put the word "Close" on the button, and set the button's tooltip to whatever you wanted.

(I don't think any of these suggestions are practical...)

Comment: Thx Tim! I don't want to hide the buttons, i'm internacionalizating an application, and i need to change the button tooltip acording to selected language

Comment: The button tooltip is internationalized according to the language assigned to the rest of the OS

Comment: humm... i was not aware of that. Thx a lot

Comment: When you change language, all text in the entire OS changes. You only need to worry about text that's under your control.