# Overwrite Windows Maximize Tooltip

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to change the tooltip of the maximize and restore down buttons in a windows form?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I'd think you could be able to make a custom class that'd override this info

Comment: I really don't think you can override that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153339/change-close-button-tooltip

Comment: @eddie_cat I saw that before I posted, but it does not have an acceptable answer. It doesn't sound like it is possible though, so thank you to the others that helped confirm.