# Change tooltip c# winform of minimize maximize or close button

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, tooltip, title

I am using DevExpress with Winform.
is it possible to change tooltip of minimize maximize or close button in the top bar of my form in winform c#?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change close button tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153339/change-close-button-tooltip)

Comment: What kind of a form is it? Ribbon or Xtra? You can set custom tooltips only on RibbonForms.

Comment: it is a ribbon? How i access the custom tooltip of the button?

Comment: it is a ribbon . Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Localizer class that inherits from DevExpress.XtraBars.Localization.BarLocalizer. Override the GetLocalizedString method and return what value you'd like for the minimize/maximize buttons. For instance:

```
public class MyRibbonLocalizer : DevExpress.XtraBars.Localization.BarLocalizer
{
    public override string Language
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
        }
    }

    public override string GetLocalizedString(BarString id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case BarString.MinimizeButton:
                return "My Minimize string";

            case BarString.MaximizeButton:
                return "My Maximize string";

            default:
                return base.GetLocalizedString(id);
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to register this localizer class in your RibbonForm in order for it to work. I typically do this within the constructor:

```
DevExpress.XtraBars.Localization.BarLocalizer.Active = new MyRibbonLocalizer();
```

This will work for both ribbons and XtraBar toolbars/XtraForms.